# Can svn client get the list of available repo from server?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn-server

Can svn client get the list of available repo from server?

For example, I've got the VisualSVN Server in our LAN, and lot of repo's on this server. How user can get the list of all existing repos in tortoise client, if user know the main server url?

Comment: Login with you SVN client to the main URL and you should see all repos.

Comment: @Tobias Knaus - I've check it with Tortoise, and this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have the required user rights?

Comment: It doesn't ask for requisites, because tortoise fail to read the content from main url

Comment: If the URL of one of your repos is `http://server-name/svn/repo1/`, then you'll see the repo content if you enter this URL in T-SVN repo browser. If you omit the "repo1/", then you should see a list of all repos. I am using SVN Edge as server, which allows that.

Comment: My case is same, repo url is https://server/svn/repo, but https://server/svn/ or https://server/ doesn't show the list of repo's in tortoise. May be this is a difference between VisualSVN and Edge.